# What is a free online New Testament commentary you recommend for diving into the historical/cultural context and the Greek/manuscripts?

Tags: new-testament, greek, bible-commentary

Although I grew up with a Bible and went to a "church," I was raised in a pseudo-Christian group but I converted to orthodox Christianity. So I am planning on reading the entire New Testament on my own. Anyways, I prefer a commentary written by a scholar, especially one who specializes in historical context and Koine Greek. Thanks!

Comment: There are too many good options! Especially because the good detailed commentaries are published for each book, not the NT as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a commentary you might find an Introduction to the New Testament helpful such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0310238595) which does go into the socio-historical context. More detailed commentaries are usually on a book-by-book basis.

You can get commentaries on every book of the Bible, such as the [New Bible Commentary](https://www.amazon.co.uk/New-Bible-Commentary-21St-Century/dp/085110648X), although this will won't go into so much detail (some books are covered better than others).

You might also find a study Bible helpful such as the [ESV Study Bible](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Study-Bible-Personal-Size-Bibles/dp/143353083X) which has lots of helpful articles as well as notes on the actual text.

Comment: I find the ESV Study Bible notes and commentaries very good indeed - but I had to buy it first!